# select/poll and one write buffer

Tags: kernel

Character device `hdlc driver`. On each write system call `hdlc frame` is created and is sent by network. I have one write buffer for all clients. `Nonblocking` and `blocking IO` is implemented. I Have problem with blocking write. Scenario:

UserA: `open(DEVICE, O_WRONLY)`

UserB: `open(DEVICE, O_WRONLY)`

UserA: `select()` //select returns: Device is ready for write

UserB: `write()`
UserA: `write()` //Device is not ready for write,cause buffer is occupied by UserB

So, select returns device readiness for writing, but we are blocked in write system call after select. Is it a suitable behaviour?

I suppose it can be fixed by creating write buffer for each open system call. Are there and other options?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of race condition and is not unique to your device. The application must be prepared for this eventuality. That is, just because select returns a file descriptor as being writable (or readable or whatever) does not guarantee that a subsequent system call on the file will not block.

The usual way of handling this is to open the file descriptor in non-blocking mode (O_NONBLOCK or O_NDELAY). Then when the situation you described happens, UserA will get a write error (with errno EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN), and should then return to select to await the device becoming writable again.